# Angular unit testing for public void method which clears input filed on mat selectionChange

Tags: angular, angular-test

I am new to this job and programming and my task is to unit test and get 80 percent code coverage. I am not able to get code coverage for this method. It says statement not covered. What am I doing wrong?

**support.component.ts**

```
searchId: string = '';

orchestration: string = '';


public clearText(){

this.searchId = '';
this.orchestration = '';

}
```

**support.component.html**

```
<mat-select id="searchselected" (selectionChange)="clearText()">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchId" [(ngModel)]=""searchId size="40" placeholder="enter value">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="orchestration" [(ngModel)]=""searchId size="40" placeholder="enter orchestration">
```

**support.component.spec.ts**

```
const spy = spy = spyon(component, 'clearText').and.callThrough();

component.searchId;
component.orchestration;


component.clearText();

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(component.searchId).toEqual('');
expect(component.orechestion).toEqual('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to spyOn the component method. External methods like service methods are spied on to avoid calling them when testing component's method.

So here you can directly call the method and test the conditions like below:

**support.component.spec.ts**

```
component.clearText();
expect(component.searchId).toEqual('');
expect(component.orechestion).toEqual('');
```

Comment: Hi Priyesha, thanks for reaching out. I did try that but still getting no coverage.

Comment: @KarthikeyanSuresh  Is test passing? Can you share details how you are getting code coverage report ?